# How to use numbers in the JSON path with node.js?

Tags: node.js, json, file, parsing

I have this JSON file:  (**EDITED**)

```
{
  "user": {
    "S-1-5-21-2659826518-2396530539-1407762326-1001": {
      "username":"xyz",
      "password":"xyz@123",
      "email":"xyz@xyz.com",
      "uid": 1100
    },
    "S-1-5-21-2659826518-2396530539-1407762326-1002": {
      "username":"abc",
      "password":"abc@456",
      "email":"abc@abc.de",
      "uid": 2222
    }
  }
}
```

(the JSON file is valid)

and I need to get the values out of it. But when I try to parse the JSON file an error appears:

```
console.log(jsonContent.S-1-5-21-2659826518-2396530539-1407762326-1001.username);
                                                                  ^^^^^
SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

also, the `username` is underlined red from my syntax highlighter. (so there is something wrong)

So I searched the internet and found nothing about it.

Here is my code:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const filename = "C:/Users/Jonas/Documents/Visual_Studio_Code/Node.js/json.json"

contents = fs.readFileSync(filename);
jsonContent = JSON.parse(contents);
console.log(jsonContent.S-1-5-21-2659826518-2396530539-1407762326-1001.username);
```

For the case I need it, I cant edit the problematic part `S-1-5-21-2659826518-2396530539-1407762326-1001`.

I also tried to set it like this: `console.log(jsonContent."S-1-5-21-2659826518-2396530539-1407762326-1001".username);` but that's ever wronger.

For any more information please ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the square bracket notation because the property name has hyphens in it which JavaScipt interprets as the minus (`-`) operator:

```
jsonContent['S-1-5-21-2659826518-2396530539-1407762326-1001'].username;
```

---

**Snippet:**

```js
const jsonContent = {
  "S-1-5-21-2659826518-2396530539-1407762326-1001": {
    "username":"xyz",
    "password":"xyz@123",
    "email":"xyz@xyz.com",
    "uid": 1100
  },
  "S-1-5-21-2659826518-2396530539-1407762326-1002": {
    "username":"abc",
    "password":"abc@456",
    "email":"abc@abc.de",
    "uid": 2222
  }
}

const name = jsonContent['S-1-5-21-2659826518-2396530539-1407762326-1001'].username;

console.log(name);
```

Comment: above the code snipped you said `jsonContent.['S-1-5-21-2659826518-2396530539-1407762326-1001'].username;` with the **.**  and in the code snipped there is no **.**?

Comment: Sorry, just a typo.

Comment: Ok but the method doesn't work on the edited JSON code in question. (I realised I forgot something). With the [] it raises Identifier Expected error. :/

Comment: Just do `jsonContent.user['S-1-5-21-2659826518-2396530539-1407762326-1001'].username`

Comment: but wait one last question: can I somehow build vars in the JSON path? e.g. an integer?

Comment: Yeah, [no problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable).